Angular 8 babel-traverse vulnerability fix?
I've an old project to be supported written in angular 8.
Is there any workaround found for this below issue?
https://deps.dev/advisory/osv/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92
Babel vulnerable to arbitrary code execution when compiling specifically crafted malicious code
This is indirectly coming from babel-template and istanbul
tried to remove it but was not successful.
There is no patch version available by babel-traverse, they are even not planning to fix this lib.
